# Is there a way to use QVariant with QVector?

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant, qvector

Is there a way to use `QVariant` with `QVector`?

I would need to implement a function to compare two vectors, for example:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVector>
#include <QString>

bool compareVectors(QVector<QVariant> vec1, QVector<QVariant> vec2)
{
    qDebug() << "Comparing vectors!";

    if( vec1 != vec2 )
    {
        qDebug() << "The vectors are different!";
        return false;
    }

    qDebug() << "The vectors are equal!";
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    QVector<double> v1;
    QVector<double> v2;
    v1 << 1 << 2;
    v2 << 3 << 4;

    QVector<QString> v3;
    QVector<QString> v4;
    v3 << "1" << "2";
    v4 << "3" << "4";

    compareVectors(v1, v1);
    compareVectors(v3, v4);

    return 0;
}
```

The two vectors passed by parameter will always have the same data type, for example:

```
compareVectors(QVector<int>, QVector<int>);
compareVectors(QVector<double>, QVector<double>);
compareVectors(QVector<QColor>, QVector<QColor>);
compareVectors(QVector<QString>, QVector<QString>);
```

When I try to run the above code I get the following error message:

> error: no matching function for call to 'compareVectors'

**Note**: I'm using Qt 5.3.

Comment: Use `std::vector`, not `QVector`. The Qt container classes are a legacy thing, generally perform worse than the std containers, have various weird quirks, are not really maintained any more & even the Qt people recommend against their use except when API boundaries force you to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use a `QVector<int>` (or `QVector<double>`) when the argument type is `QVector<QVariant>`.

I would suggest making `compareVectors` a function template.

```
template <typename T>
bool compareVectors(QVector<T> vec1, QVector<T> vec2)
{
    qDebug() << "Comparing vectors!";

    if( vec1 != vec2 )
    {
        qDebug() << "The vectors are different!";
        return false;
    }

    qDebug() << "The vectors are equal!";
    return true;
}
```